# Explode string php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho um problema no mínimo estranho, pelo menos para mim.

Tenho uma string em php:

```
$str='10,20,30,40';
explode(',',$str);
```

Quando faço o explode da string e passo o resultado para uma vista via $ajax obtenho o seguinte resultado:

> *"\n\n10203040"*

Alguém me pode explicar o porque do *"\n\n"*?

Comment: Já tentou colocar o resultado do explode dentro do `json_encode` antes de enviar?

Comment: É quebra de linha, usa um `trim()` na string.

Comment: @rray faltou a resposta :)

Comment: Já tentei não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Ou poderás fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
 $json = str_replace('\n', '', $json);
?>
```

**é uma opção quando tiveres \n entre texto**

Comment: Já tentei e não funciona.

Comment: Explica teu erro e tentarei ajudar

Comment: Obrigado a todos e peço desculpa por só estar a responder agora. Já resolvi o problema, apaguei o código e voltei a escrever de novo e funcinou lindamente. Porquê? Não faço ideia...